# IMDB - Node.js + cheerio print list of items

Tags: jquery, node.js, parsing, cheerio

I would like to print list of items from div class (list detail eplist).

from this url -> https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108778/episodes?season=1&ref_=tt_eps_sn_1

While I print my list I get only one elements, why it is happened?

```
        $('.list detail eplist').each((i, element) => {
            console.log("++++++++++++++++++++");
            const itemId = $(element).text();
            console.log("++++++++++++++++++++");
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want:

```
$('.list_item')
```